# How do you prevent additional .keyup event after selecting data list item in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using AJAX to auto populate html datalist, why does selecting datalist item trigger another event? I am using jquery keyup to auto suggest queries, after I select a list item the string is placed in the input box correctly but then it triggers the keyup event again which makes the datalist dropdown stay open, covering button.

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchTerm').keyup(function (e) {
        var search = $(this).val();
        $.post(host/search, {search: search}, function (data) {
            $('#list').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

I expect clicking a datalist item to populate the input field with the string selected and then the datalist to disappear, but instead it triggers an additional .keyup event and persists.

The auto suggest feature is quite common so I apologize if I am overlooking anything obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var keyupFired = false;
  $('#text').keyup(function(e) {
    if (!keyupFired) {
      console.log("Yes...");
      keyupFired = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert("OK!!!");
        keyupFired = false;
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      console.log("No...");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='text' name='text' placeholder='please enter text....' />
```

```js
$(function() {
  var keyupFired = false; // intialize the flag
  if (!keyupFired) {
    keyupFired = true; // before starting the task
    $('#searchTerm').keyup(function(e) {
      var search = $(this).val();
      $.post(host / search, {
        search: search
      }, function(data) {
        $('#list').html(data);
        keyupFired = false; //completed its task so again make `keyupFired =false` 
      });
    });
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

To implement this functionality you need to maintain one flag.

Comment: Your answer did not get rid of the drop down. Works exactly the same as before. Also not sure what the flag is supposed to be doing since it will never stop the AJAX call.

Comment: this will work for sure... I have tried this in my functionality. add with code snippet with this answer,so i can believe this is not working.

Comment: Okay I tried your new implementation and it still does not work. If I change the flag after the AJAX call to true instead of false it works as it should but only if I click on one of the initial list items. So if type one letter and select from the initial datalist, it behaves perfectly. But any additional key presses are not registered because the flag is true. When it's false it will always make the AJAX call. The issues is when selecting a datalist item it should not make an additional call. The flags have no way of preventing that because selecting a datalist item registers  a keyup event.

Comment: @jmoney  Have you seen the First example in which I have demonstrated that next request will happen only when We want. & I don't know what you want... So I have tried hard to give my best answer according to your question & I did. Thank you!

Comment: I was looking for a solution based on registering a click event with the datalist or preventing the input change from triggering keyup. That seems to be the simplest way to do it. When I have time I will just check if the query string has been sent before and cancel it. I wish I could just prevent the input box change from registering a keyup event though.

Comment: @jmoney Sorry brother I can't fulfill your requirement, what you ask! & I have not downvoted your question!